# Defaultinterface in TChromium is missing

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-2007, twebbrowser

We are trying to change the builtin browser component from TWebBrowser to [TChromium](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/).
It is used mostly for displaying maps from Google and Bing. The communication from the javascript to Delphi is done with COM.

When trying to change the browser to TChromium it fails to compile this code.

```
if supports(fBrowser.defaultInterface, IOleObject, fOLE) then
```

because defaultInterface is missing from TChromium.

**EDIT:**
Is it possible to still communicate from javascript to Delphi with Chromium?
I'm aware of that they are not compatible and I have to rewrite code. I just want to know how to get a result from javascript to delphi. Note I am using Delphi 2007 so the extended RTTI cannot be used.

Regards 
Roland Bengtsson

Comment: Are you sure that `TChromium` even supports `IOleObject`?

Comment: Chromium probably doesn't support `IOleObject`. What are you using `TWebBrowser.DefaultInterface` for? If you have a specific problem try to describe it in more detail. Perhaps it's possible to achieve the same result with Chromium in a different way.

Comment: I second TOndrej's suggestion. If "Chromium" has anything to do with the "Chrome" browser, then it's very likely to support anything you might want to do. But it's definitively not a drop-in replacement for `TWebBrowser`. Ie: copy-pasted code designed for TWebBrowser will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TChromium, you can invoke scripts easily via `ExecuteJavaScript`. And you can invoke Delphi code from scripts, which you can use to send return values back from a JavaScript function to Delphi. 
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893029/how-to-expose-native-functions-to-javascript-in-a-web-page-using-chromium-and-d/6895111#6895111) and my answer there about doing this using extensions.

There also seems to be work in progress for functions like `EexecuteScriptAndReturnValue` but as the time of writing they are not contained in the trunk.

And regarding `TWebBrowser.DefaultInterface` I agree with Cosmin: the best analogy is probably `TChromium.Browser` as you can access frames and subsequently DOM, etc. from there.

Answer (score 5):

I never used it myself, but `TChromium` appears to be a wrapper around the "Chromium" web browser, while the original `TWebBrowser` from Delphi is a wrapper around an IE Browser.

`TWebBrowser.defaultInstance` gives you the COM object of the IE Browser. For the Chromium browser you can apparently use `TChromium.Browser`, it gives you an object of type `ICefBrowser`. The `TChromium` people were smart not to name the property `defaultInstance` because there's a lot of code out there casting from the return of `defaultInstance` to other interface types: If `TChromium.Browser` was named the same, the cast would compile and fail at run time. Because the IE Browser is obviously not a Chrome browser, and I doubt the Chromium browser fully implements all IE interfaces.

Comment: Yes, that what I suspected. But it should be some way to communicate between javascript and Delphi ?

Comment: As I've said, I haven't used TChromium myself. I simply looked at some of the source files on it's [code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/) repository. There's no documentation over there, and I can't judge the quality of the in-source comments. Your best bet is to use the information from here: http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/ because that's what TChromium is wrapping.

Comment: Have a look at and experiment with `TCefRTTIExtension`. From what little I understood from the code so far, it declares a native extension to the V8 Javascript engine and seems to use RTTI to resolve property and method names to invoke your Delphi code.

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/delphichromiumembedded/browse_thread/thread/1793e7ca66012f0c

Comment: It seems that it is easier with D2010 and extended RTTI. Unfortunately I use D2007 and I cannot upgrade now until Bold for Delphi is rewritten for Unicode.

Comment: Yes it's easier with D2010 and higher but still possible with D2007. Have a look at `cefclient.dpr` and how `TExtension` is used there.