# How to expose "native functions" to Javascript in a web page using Chromium and Delphi 6?

Tags: javascript, delphi, chromium, embedded-v8

I have successfully embedded Chromium into my Delphi 6 projects with the help of [Delphi Chromium Embedded](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/).  Now I want to be able to execute Javascript code and the have results returned to my host Delphi app.  My current method is to call ExecuteJavascript() and use a DOM element that the Javascript call writes its results to, and poll that element in a TTimer method from Delphi to retrieve the results.  However, I read about using native functions and V8 extensions to have the Javascript call "call back" into my Delphi code as a way to receive results instead:

http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=180

I would like to try this and I also would like to know how to attach Delphi based event listeners to DOM elements in the web page (onblur, onmousedown, etc.).  I am looking for some samples that would show me how to do these two things if anyone knows where to find them.

Comment: Wow, Delphi-6 where you have to do all Unicode by hand and Chromium with full Unicode support. Now that sounds like an impedance mismatch to me :)

Comment: "Impedance mismatch".  There's an electronics engineer in the room folks. :)  You're right, but Delphi 6 is still my favorite IDE.  At least for now.

Comment: I wish I was an electronics engineer; I never had the chance studying it, but still have the feeling that knowing about electronic engineering and having a feel for what can go wrong there is tremendously useful in the IT. I understand you like Delphi 6, but urge to you look at more current versions. Recently I had to go back, and there was so much I missed...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Attaching listeners is quite easy (only in older versions of CEF):

```
procedure MouseDownCallback(const Event: ICefDomEvent);
begin
  ShowMessage('Mouse down on '+Event.Target.Name);
end;

procedure AttachMouseDownListenerProc(const Doc: ICefDomDocument);
begin
  Doc.Body.AddEventListenerProc('mousedown', True, MouseDownCallback);
end;

procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ChromiumComponent.Browser.MainFrame.VisitDomProc(AttachMouseDownListenerProc);
end;
```

Regarding the extended functions for getting JavaScript results directly: the trunk doesn't contain them (yet?). Seems to be work in progress.

**Edit**:

Getting rid of polling via **extensions**:

It is indeed possible for your JavaScript code to call back into your Delphi code using extensions. Furthermore you can send values from JavaScript to Delphi - this could be used to transfer results without the need to poll.

First in your `initialization` section register the extension, which creates a JavaScript object later to be used when calling back:

```
procedure RegisterExtension;
var
  Code:string;
begin

  Code :=
   'var cef;'+
   'if (!cef)'+
   '  cef = {};'+
   'if (!cef.test)'+
   '  cef.test = {};'+
   '(function() {'+
   '  cef.test.__defineGetter__(''test_param'', function() {'+
   '    native function GetTestParam();'+
   '    return GetTestParam();'+
   '  });'+
   '  cef.test.__defineSetter__(''test_param'', function(b) {'+
   '    native function SetTestParam();'+
   '    if(b) SetTestParam(b);'+
   '  });'+
   '  cef.test.test_object = function() {'+
   '    native function GetTestObject();'+
   '    return GetTestObject();'+
   '  };'+
   '})();';

  CefRegisterExtension('example/v8', Code, TMyHandler.Create as ICefv8Handler);
end;

initialization
  RegisterExtension;
```

`TMyHandler`'s `Execute` will be invoked later. `TMyHandler` is defined as

```
TMyHandler = class(TCefv8HandlerOwn)
protected
  function Execute(const name: ustring; const obj: ICefv8Value;
    const arguments: TCefv8ValueArray; var retval: ICefv8Value;
    var exception: ustring): Boolean; override;
end;
```

The implementation for demonstration purposes is simple for now:

```
function TMyHandler.Execute(const name: ustring; const obj: ICefv8Value; const arguments: TCefv8ValueArray; var retval: ICefv8Value; var exception: ustring): Boolean;
begin
  ShowMessage('Execute!');
end;
```

Now to test calling into Delphi from JavaScript simply do:

```
ChromiumComponent.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript('cef.test.test_object().GetMessage();', 'about:blank', 0);
```

This should display the message box saying "Execute!".

I pulled the demo script from a sample named **cefclient** which you can find in the **\demos\cefclient** folder in the component root dir. The extension sample code is a bit hidden and mingled with other demo code. But of special interest for us is the implementation of `TExtension.Execute` (the equivalent to my `TMyHandler.Execute`). There you can find how to determine which function is being called and how to pass parameters. ([Link to the code.](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/source/browse/trunk/demos/cefclient/cefclient.dpr))

Comment: Thank you Heinrich.  That's what I needed.  "Regarding the extended functions for getting JavaScript results...".  One of the threads I read indicated that there was some concern about this because it would involve blocking the calling thread while a result was returned.  I understand that concern but personally I'd like to see it with the usual caveats about blocking threads.  But that's my opinion.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I fully agree that the extended functions could be useful, especially `executeScriptAndReturnValue` sounds handy.