# DCEF3 - Delphi Chromium Embedded - communication between Javascript and application code

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded

I'm using DCEF3, revision 24038bd3a600, and I should want to communicate between Javascript code in browser and Delphi code of application. 
I know how it can be accomplished from Delphi code and Javascript, by using framework's method 'ExecuteJavascript', but what about the reverse (from Javascript to Delphi/application code) ?
I haven't found such a situation in demos/examples (GUIclient, specifically...).

Comment: you have to register a V8 extension (JavaScript code that calls native functions); you can see an example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6895111/833188)

Comment: Ok, I have done so in a older version (DCEF, not DCEF3) but now in DCEF3 it seems not working. Are You sure it's still possible to do so ?

Comment: it seems so, `ceflib.pas` has a reference to `cef_register_extension`. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/issues/detail?id=20&q=extension) you can find an example

Comment: It's not working, CefRegisterExtension always return false and extension doesn't work in web page.

Comment: can you test `guiclient`? There is a test in it for extensions, see at the end of [this source code](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/browse/demos/guiclient/main.pas)

Comment: ok, now is working, but only with ShowMessage as command executed in Delphi application. With other commands or functions it doesn't work. Any idea about that ?

Comment: sorry, can't test Delphi environment

Answer (score 3):

There is a **guiclient** demo if official source code to do this. Look at [main.pas](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/browse/demos/guiclient/main.pas) file.

The code below is a class extension :

```
class function TTestExtension.hello: string;
begin
  Result := 'Hello from Delphi';
end;
```

The code below register the extension class :

```
TCefRTTIExtension.Register('app', TTestExtension);
```

The code below call your native code from a HTML page :

```
<script>
alert ( app.hello() );
</script>
```

The code below call your native code from embedded browser :

```
crm.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript('alert ( app.hello() );', 'about:blank', 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

A quite easy workaround is to catch the browser's OnJSDialog / OnConsoleMessage event, do an Alert/log in JS when there's something to execute. Tell the delphi part in the alert's message what to do. You need to interpret it as a string (maybe with a scripting library or direct parsing). No direct call of delphi code is possible with it, but I guess it's safer this way anyway.